# How to trigger animation on child element when the parent is 75% into its animation ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to programatically(using Javascript) know when an animation is 75% complete ? actually i have alot of nested HTML elements that need to be animated using an animation delay property and the way it works is the nested animation should trigger , when the parent element is 75% complete , i know how the animationend event works , but thats not really what i am looking for , see the **[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dyt1q4g8/)**

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

animation delay code:

```
div p {
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-name: icon-bounce-in;
  -moz-animation-name: icon-bounce-in;
  -o-animation-name: icon-bounce-in;
  animation-name: icon-bounce-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
  -o-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .375s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .375s;
  -o-animation-delay: .375s;
  animation-delay: .375s;
}
```

(not the best visual example) See how i have delayed the execution of the `p` animation by 75% manually , but how would i do this programatically in javascript , for a large set of elements (not necessarily add an animation delay to the child elements , but check when the parent element is 75% into its animation stage and then trigger the animation on the child element).

Comment: GreenSocks' tweenMax allows you to stagger animation triggers.

http://greensock.com/tweenmax

Comment: @Korgrue i know that :D thanks , great library , but i'd prefer a vanilla JS or jQuery solution , i've seen solutions using animation delay , but that not 100% what i want , either ways , thanks for the comment .

Comment: I only recommend greensock because I came from a Flash background and it was my animation library of choice at the time. It is very robust, perhaps too much so for your implementation. You can also check out tweenLight which is a smaller library, but honestly I am not sure if that one support animation staggering.

Comment: how about making the second animation delay for 3/4 the duration of the initial animation? prolly not deterministic but still could be close?

Comment: @SamJacobs by hardcoding ? thats why i have done in the fiddle example :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: I don't think there is any way to obtain the current percentage other than using timeouts or other methods. There are no built-in properties or functions which can give this.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use jQuery delay to stagger animations.

[Update to your FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dyt1q4g8/3/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="outer">
  <p id="inner">hello world</p>
</div>
<button id="clicker">click</button>
```

#### Javascript

```
$('#clicker').click(function() {
    var outerDuration = 500;
  $('#outer').css({top: '-50px', position: 'relative'})
             .animate({top: 0}, outerDuration);
  $('#inner').css({position: 'relative'}) // had trouble animating position, maybe just me
             .delay(outerDuration*.75) // the magic
             .animate({top: '-50px'}, 0, function() { // make use of oncomplete callback to properly obey delay
                 $('#inner').animate({top: 0}, outerDuration)
             });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

ok this is a little trick i played there [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtd8535/)

what i did is, i calculated the distance the `div` will travel in whole transition and set a watch(`setInterval`) on it and calculated its dimenation on a time interval of 10 mili seconds (this is adjustable), as soon as `div`/child `p` traveled the 75% distance i pushed an alert, you can call any function or do anything there, here is code

```
var start=null;//distance covered in transition
var flag=1; //depending on direction of transition, -1 for down to up
var pos;
var distance=200;

var a=setInterval(function(){
   if(start==null){
     start=$('div').position().top;
    }

   pos=$('div').position().top;
   console.log(pos,start,distance);
   if(pos>=(start+(0.75*distance))){
    alert("animation is 75% done");
    clearInterval(a);
   }

},1);
```

Comment: nice try and could be a possible solution.